# How can a RESTful API client save an oAuth token for future requests?

Tags: java, rest, session, authentication, oauth

A RESTful API service needs an oAuth token to be sent with each request. So a Java Apache based client has to first request token like so...

```
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpClient;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.HttpMethod;
import org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.GetMethod;

String loginUrl = "https://jerseyrules.com/api/login1?name=joe&cleartext=schmoe";
HttpMethod method = new GetMethod(loginUrl);
String responseCode = httpClient.executeMethod(method);
String token = method.getResponseBodyAsString();
```

Only now can the client call the actual service methods of that API and it must pass the oAuth token as an Authorization request header for each service.

Supposing this client code will be called multiple times in batch mode, for example to send emails to a list of recipients. To send the actual email requires a call to the RESTful API service.

Does the client have to request the oAuth token again for each email send? Is there a way the client can get an oAuth token once and save it somewhere to be used for subsequent calls? What is the best place to save that oAuth token? Supposing the token will expire in 3600 seconds.

Can the cookies of the httpClient be used to store the token..

```
httpClient.getState().getCookies()
```

Comment: You can save the token in any kind of storage place you want. What really matters is to send it into each subsequent request using the right mechanism. Often the token will be send as a custom header.

Comment: Thanks, but do you have any suggestions on the storage and the mechanism for re transmission?

Comment: You can take a look at an example here: https://github.com/alainlompo/performance-hub/blob/master/gatling/secured-websockets-tests/GAtlingSecuredWebsocketLoadTest.scala. if not helpful try sharing a more detailed source

Answer (score 1):

Try this thing:

```
method.getParams().setCookiePolicy(CookiePolicy.RFC_2109);
```

http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/cookies.html